# I can't understand the meaning of the phrase in a book

Tags: meaning, literature

So I am very interested what this means: "Resin streaks outline his light switch, and...", because to me it really seems like a bunch of random words.
As I don't understand this piece, I can't say whether the whole sentence will be helpful to figure out what the author is talking about or not, but, just in case, here it is: "Resin streaks outline his light switch, and his bedsheet is pockmarked with black circles".

Comment: "His light switch is outlined by streaks of resin." Perhaps it looks something like [this picture](https://cdn.xl.thumbs.canstockphoto.com/traditional-old-light-switch-on-the-wall-stock-photos_csp10161237.jpg). 'Resin' and 'burn marks' could refer to the carelessness of a pot-head.

Comment: oh gosh, I thought Resin was a name!! Thank you xD

Comment: BTW that sentence is **all over** the internet. Please do basic research before asking!

Comment: Okay, sorry! I should have googled resin first.

Comment: The [whole sentence](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Resin+streaks+outline+his+light+switch,+and+his+bedsheet+is+pockmarked+with+black+circles%22&source=lmns&client=firefox-b-d&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj39bCO_ePqAhUQ1-AKHVMwCT4Q_AUoAHoECAEQAA) is there.

Answer (score 1):

This is taken (although you didn't say) from a novel called "It's Kind of a Funny Story" by Ned Vizzini, which is used in a number of ESL courses.

> There’s always pot at Aaron’s house; he has a room with an entirely
> separate ventilation system and lockable door that his parents could
> rent out as another apartment. Resin streaks outline his light switch,
> and his bedsheet is pockmarked with black circles. There are stains on
> there, too, shimmery stains which indicate certain activities that
> take place between Aaron and his girlfriend. I look at them (the
> stains, then the couple). I’m jealous. But then again, I’m beyond
> jealous.

Pot is another name for marijuana or cannabis (a drug) which is consumed by smoking, as dried plants, or as resin extracted from plants. The resin is sticky and can stain things, especially if the user is not inclined to be tidy or clean (this is clear from the text). There are streaks of resin (from people's fingers) around the light switch (on the wall) forming an outline.